# Where should I apply for schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, tourist-visas, customs-and-immigration

I am going to be visiting Europe this July specifically the countries of Sweden (4-5 days), Italy (6 days), Malta (1 day) and Switzerland (3 days). I had originally booked my visa appointment at the Sweden Embassy since that's my point of entry (and I have a round trip from the USA to Stockholm planned). However, I think I may end up spending more days in Italy. Now, it looks like the Italian embassy has NO visa dates until July! What I want to know is whether the embassy only needs to know you're exiting the Schengen area for sure in order to issue a visa or whether there will be issues that I'm getting a visa from Sweden when I'm spending more days in Italy. I am an F1 student in the USA with an Indian passport.

Comment: Note that the issue about the Italian embassy having no available open dates is immaterial. The rules are the rules and they say nothing about eligibility to apply at another consulate if the consulate you’re supposed to apply at has no dates.

Comment: @user56513 your comment is correct.  However, if I were in Preeti Ramaraj's situation, I would seriously consider delaying my travel to Italy by a day or two.  That would make Sweden the correct country to consider the application.  Not everyone can achieve this with such a small modification of the proposed itinerary.

Comment: @phoog Agreed. Should work around his itinerary to be eligible to apply to the embassy that suits him best.

Comment: Indeed, I would adjust the itinerary for purposes of the application, but I think in a case where the difference is two days, it would also be save to switch _back_ to the original itinerary after entering Schengen (if desired and feasible).